# Java: Creating a Delimiter Method that has Input/Output

Tags: java, arrays, string, methods, delimiter

I'm working on a study problem from class and essentially it reads a string, and a character.  The character is the delimiter.  It will then search the string for the delimiter and create an array in equal length to the number of times the delimiter is found.  It then assigns each character or string to its own spot in the array and returns it.

Maybe I am over thinking things, but the just of it is to not rely on the various string methods and to sort of create your own.  How can I get this method to only assign the string/char found in the one that is read to one position in the array and not all as well as stop it from adding unnecessary output?  Help/Suggestions greatly appreciated

```
public static String[] explode(String s, char d){
    String []c;
    int count = 1;
    //checks to see how many times the delimter appears in the string and creates an      array of corresponding size
    for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++){
        if(d == s.charAt(i))
            count ++;
    }
    c = new String [count];
    //used for checking to make sure the correct number of elements are found
    System.out.println(c.length);
    //goes through the the input string "s" and checks to see if the delimiter is found
    //when it is found it makes c[j] equal to what is found
    //once it has cycled through the length of "s" and filled each element for c, it returns the array
    for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < c.length; j++){
                if(d == s.charAt(i))
                    c[j] += s.substring(i-1);
            }
    }
    //provides output for the array [c] just to verify what was found
    for(int y = 0; y < c.length; y++)
        System.out.println(c[y]);
    return c;
}
public static void main(String [] args){
    String test = "a,b,c,d";
    char key = ',';
    explode(test,key);
}


    ^The following will output:
    4
    nulla,b,c,db,c,dc,d
    nulla,b,c,db,c,dc,d
    nulla,b,c,db,c,dc,d
    nulla,b,c,db,c,dc,d

    I'm aiming for:
    4
    a
    b
    c
    d
```

Thank you

Comment: You don't seem to have a particular question here. Your general approach is right, but SO isn't for general code review (try codereview.stackexchange.com for that). If you have a specific issue, please edit your question to ask it. (Also, if you're rolling your own but aren't banned from using the Collections, `List` might be a lot easier to deal with than a bare array.)

Comment: I'm going to try and rebuild using what you suggested chrysalis.  I appreciate the suggestion and the heads up as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you could try something like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    explode("a,b,c,d", ',');
}

public static void explode(final String string, final char delimiter){
    int length = 1;
    for(final char c : string.toCharArray())
        if(delimiter == c)
            length++;
    if(length == 1)
        return;
    final String[] array = new String[length];
    int index, prev = 0, i = 0;
    while((index = string.indexOf(delimiter, prev)) > -1){
        array[i++] = string.substring(prev, index);
        prev = index+1;
    }
    array[i] = string.substring(prev);
    System.out.println(length);
    for(final String s : array)
        System.out.println(s);
}
```

Output of the program above is:

`4`

`a`

`b`

`c`

`d`

Or if you want to utilize a `List<String>` instead (and Java 8), you could remove a couple of lines by doing something like this:

```
public static void explode(final String string, final char delimiter){
    final List<String> list = new LinkedList<>();
    int index, prev = 0;
    while((index = string.indexOf(delimiter, prev)) > -1){
        list.add(string.substring(prev, index));
        prev = index+1;
    }
    list.add(string.substring(prev));
    System.out.println(list.size());
    list.forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

Comment: Thank you Josh, I understand everything but the following line.

array[i] = string.substring(pref);  

How is the index being incremented if it's outside the loop?

Comment: When the loop exits, `i` is equal to `length-1`.